# Python: read nth value on every line from text file into array

Tags: python, arrays, list, text-files

I have a very large text file containing XYZ data, with each value separated by a single space:

```
100000 200000 2.5698
200000 200000 1.9863
200000 400000 2.2587
...
```

I'm looking to create an array of only the last value in each line (i.e. the Z value). What I have so far is:

```
with open(xyzFile) as f:
    for eachLine in f:
        tmpLine = f.readline()
        print("### tmpLine: {0}".format(tmpLine))
```

This prints out the first line of the file, as expected:

```
### tmpLine: 253575 705575 83.710655
```

How can I grab the third value and iterate to next line in text file? I guess I need a for loop somewhere here. I know how to append the value to the array, which would go in between these two processes:

```
zArray.append(zValue)
```

Comment: did you try using `tmpLine.split()`? Then access the index you want.

Comment: When you do `f.readline()` you're advancing the pointer in file to the next line for each line read - is that what you're wanting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this by doing `split` and `strip`(if need) wisely

```
with open(xyzFile) as f:
    for eachLine in f:
        print("### tmpLine: {0}".format(eachLine.strip().split()[-1].strip()))
```

Comment: I believe since you are using the no args version of split, it will strip the whitespace for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using numpy's `loadtxt`, documentation is found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). There is a handy `usecols` argument that you can set to 2, to only read the 3rd column. Using the small bit of data you provide the following code generates a 1D array of the 3rd column

```
import numpy as np
z = np.loadtxt("filename.txt", usecols=2)

print (z)
# output is [ 2.5698  1.9863  2.2587]
```

Comment: This function is awesome! However, I think you should change `usecols=2` by `usercols=-1` to be sure that you will get the last column in every cases.

Comment: When I tried this I got an error: `File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 703, in loadtxt
    usecols = list(usecols)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 2):

You will read the line and split the line on the basis of space `tmpLine.split(' ')`, then you will get an array of that line.

Of that array fetch the third element.`tmpLine.split(' ')[2]`

```
zArray = []

with open(xyzFile) as f:
    for eachLine in f:
        zArray.append(eachLine.split(' ')[2])
```

Another way that's [List Comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) as suggested by Jon is :

```
with open(xyzFile) as f:

        zArray = [eachline.split(' ')[2] for eachline in f]
```

Comment: You're reading a line and then reading another line each loop... so you're discarding half the file here

Comment: @JonClements yeah my bad, rectified.

Comment: Might as well make it: `with open('xyzFile) as f: zArray = [line.split(' ')[2] for line in f]`

Comment: @JonClements added that too.

Comment: Turns out the xyz file has `\n` at end of each row, which is carried through when using the above. Accepted alternate answer as this strips out references to `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` module

```
with open(xyzFile) as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=" "):
        print(row[-1])
```

Which yields something like this:

```
2.5698
1.9863
2.2587
```